# how to call out the results from mysql in if else statements

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I want the results to show, but it kept on directing to my login.php 
What is the mistake I made? 

Firstly, I want to find those students who have a gpa of 3, and if there are records, i want it to filter again to those with jobscope of Admin only.

```
<?php
        include("....");

        $conn = dbConnect();

        if (!$conn)
            die("Cannot connect to database");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE gpa > '3';";
        $result = mysqli_query($query, $conn);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
          {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
          if ($row['jobscope'] == 'Admin')
          echo $row('name');
          }
        else
          {
          header(login.php)
          }             
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you include the jobscope filter in your where clause?

Comment: Is gpa is save as an INT you don't need quote, quotes are for strings

Comment: @Kevin it still direct back to login.php

Comment: Try your query without the WHERE clause to make sure it's pulling results back period?

Comment: You are not even verifying whether `$result` contains a valid result set before trying to work with it.  You should check for and handle errors at this step before trying to check `num_rows`.

Comment: @MikeBrant so how do i verify $result ?

Answer (score 3):

change:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query, $conn);
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

[mysqli::query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) expects `db link` as first parameter.

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

Further to compare numeric, change `WHERE gpa > '3'` to `WHERE gpa > 3`

For debug remove the `else` and `echo mysqli_error($conn);`

Change `header(login.php)` to `header("Location: login.php");`

Change `$row('name')` to `$row['name']`

---

```
$conn = dbConnect();

if (!$conn) die("Cannot connect to database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE gpa > 3;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

// check for errors
var_dump($result, mysqli_error($conn));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  // check your row
  var_dump($row);

  if ($row['jobscope'] == 'Admin') {
    echo $row['name'];
  }
}/* else
{
  header("Location: login.php");
}*/
```

Comment: it is still directed to login.php

Comment: Additionally, I don't believe the semi-colon belongs at the end of the SQL query.   Not sure if it would cause an error, but it shouldn't be there (not part of SQL)

Comment: i did the necessary changes and it is still not showing the results. is my coding to call out the names of the students correct? i am new to if else statement.. @Jonny 5

Comment: Remove the `else` and `var_dump($result, mysqli_error($conn))`; Do you get rows?

Comment: did you mean to type it like this?   

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }

Comment: @Jonny5 when i run your codes, it came out as NULL NULL 
what does that mean?

Comment: @Angelica Updated the answer and sample

Comment: @Jonny5 why is it still showing NULL NULL after I have made the changes?

Comment: @Angelica Did you ever successfully query the database from any script yet? Please show your `dbConnect()` function, verify first, that you are connected. First after `dbConnect()` do `var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: @Jonny5 when i run the query, it is able to show the results where the gpa is more than 3.

Comment: @Jonny5 after i typed the var_dump(mysqli_error($conn)); it came out as NULL NULL NULL. why is that so?

Comment: @Angelica I don't know what's going on there. Sorry i have to capitulate :) Start it simple, first try to get any result out of db and [debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging).

Comment: @Jonny5 thank you so much for your help.. i will start by going step by step. :)